# How to write a JSONObject to a file, which has JSONArray inside it, in Java?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have JSON file, that I need to read, edit and write out again.

Reading works fine, I struggle with the write part of the JSON Array in my data.

I use [JSON.simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) library to work with JSON in Java.

The file looks like this:

```
{
    "maxUsers":100,
    "maxTextLength":2000,
    "maxFileSize":2000,
    "services":
    [
        {
            "serviceName":"Яндекc",
            "className":"YandexConnector.class",
            "isEnabled":true
        },

        {
            "serviceName":"Google",
            "className":"GoogleConnector.class",
            "isEnabled":false
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to write JSON-data (variable `obj`) to file, the `services` array is broken. My writing code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("maxUsers", this.getMaxUsers());
obj.put("maxTextLength", this.getMaxTextLength());
obj.put("maxFileSize", this.getMaxFileSize()); 

JSONArray servicesJSON = new JSONArray();
ArrayList<Service> servicesArray = this.getServices();
for(int i=0; i< servicesArray.size(); i++)
{
    servicesJSON.add(servicesArray.get(i));
}
obj.put("services", servicesJSON);


FileWriter file = new FileWriter(filename);                
obj.writeJSONString(file);
file.flush();
file.close();
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "services":
    [
        translator.settings.Service@121c5df,
        translator.settings.Service@45f4ae
    ],
    "maxTextLength":2000,
    "maxUsers":100,
    "maxFileSize":2000
}
```

How can I write the JSON data correctly to a file, if I have it in a JSONArray like `services` ?

---

The code, where I read the JSON data from the file (that works fine):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filename));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

setMaxUsers((Long) jsonObject.get("maxUsers"));
setMaxTextLength((Long) jsonObject.get("maxTextLength"));
setMaxFileSize((Long) jsonObject.get("maxFileSize"));
// get all list of services
JSONArray serv = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("services");

for (int i = 0; i < serv.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject service = (JSONObject) serv.get(i);
    Service servec = new Service();
    servec.setServiceName((String) service.get("serviceName"));
    servec.setClassName((String) service.get("className"));
    servec.setIsEnabled((Boolean) service.get("isEnabled"));

    services.add(i, servec);
}
```

The editing part is not yet written, so I call the writing part directly after the reading.

---

Comment: There is definitely a problem with the edit part, which you're not showing. You store instances of Service class in your JSON array, instead of storing JSONObject instances.

Comment: Show us how you create your JSON-data `obj`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ,  I add part with code . can you look at it?

Comment: @JBNizet -I add part with code where I worked with object JSON . can you look at it?

Comment: Don't forget to show how you serialize it back to the file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, i'm sorry that i forgot to show it) now all code, that need?

Comment: @alena_fox_spb Yes, now its clear what the problem is. You don't convert your values to `primitves` or `String` before adding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [examples](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples) of `JSON-simple`.

It says here that you need to put the Objects one by one into the Array, using only `primitive` and `String` values. You may use `Collections` like `Map` that by themselves only contain `String` or `primitive` values.

```
  JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
  list.add("foo");
  list.add(new Integer(100));
  list.add(new Double(1000.21));
  list.add(new Boolean(true));
  list.add(null);
  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
  list.writeJSONString(out);
```

So, adding your `Services` is not allowed and won't work. You should add a `toMap` method in it where you convert it to a `Map` and `fromMap` to convert it back.

Like this (in `Services.java`):

```
 public Map toMap() {
     HashMap<String, String> serviceAsMap = new HashMap<>();
     servicesAsMap.put("serviceName", serviceName);
     servicesAsMap.put("className", this.class.getName() + ".class");
     servicesAsMap.put("isEnabled", isEnabled);
     // ... continue for all values
     return servicesAsMap;
 }
```

then you can use that `Map` to populate your `JSONArray` like this:

```
        JSONArray servicesJSON = new JSONArray();
        ArrayList<Service> servicesArray = this.getServices();
        for(int i=0; i< servicesArray.size(); i++)
        {
            servicesJSON.add(servicesArray.get(i).toMap()); // use the toMap method here.
        }
        obj.put("services", servicesJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JSONArray [Documentation](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html#writeJSONString(java.util.List,%20java.io.Writer)).Here you will get list of methods available.This `JSONArray` is inherited from `java.util.ArrayList`,so we can use the methods available for `ArrayList` to `JSONArray`.

```
 JSONArray userList = JSONFile.readJSONArray("users.json");
 JSONArray newuserList = new JSONArray() ;  
 JSONObject jsonobject , newjsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                jsonobject = (JSONObject) userList.get(i);

                String id = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
                String pass = (String) jsonObject.get("password");
                newuserList.add(jsonObject); 
 // Here we are putting json object into newuserList which is of JSONArray type
            try{
                FileWriter  file = new FileWriter( "/users.json",false);

                newuserList.writeJSONString(newuserList, file);
                file.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e  ){

                e.getMessage();

            }
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: When writing json to file, it should call the static method of JSONArray: `JSONArray.writeJSONString(newuserList, file);` in current version of json-simple.