# how to write json to file?

Tags: android, json

How can I  write a new file with my specific json's format? how can i do this with `JSONObject`? i need some java code and i want too save this file in assets.
my json is:

```
{
    "word": "a",
    "Data": [
        {
            "meanings": [
                {
                    "meaning": "b",
                    "synonyms": [
                        "c"
                    ],
                    "examples": [
                        "d"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "wordForms": ["e"],
            "word": "a",
            "pos": "g",
            "phoneticText": "h"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you mean, you want to store the json into a  file ?

Comment: @Blackbelt yes i want to store the json into a file

Comment: it is nothing more that storing a String on a file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Google it ?

Look here: [How to write a JSONObject to a file, which has JSONArray inside it, in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211441/how-to-write-in-file-a-jsonobject-which-has-jsonarray-inside-it-in-java&ved=0CCIQFjACahUKEwjjm8-k5frGAhVGz3IKHbK-B-Q&usg=AFQjCNFN_-iavVFlfAr0jLGfX5Pwt1hH9g&sig2=v3tcJt5u-0Jt9qrq9mnvfw)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. its simple. put your file in local for test. inside htdocs folder create a folder abc and inside it create a json file with .php extension and use the following code. works fine.

```
  <?php
   header('Content-type:application/json');
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('british');
     $select = mysql_query('SELECT id,title,content,photo from news ');

    $rows=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
  array_push($rows, array('id'=>$row[0],'title'=>$row[1],  
'content'=>strip_tags($row[2]), 
'photo'=>'http://10.0.2.2/json/images/'.$row[3]));
}
echo json_encode((array("result"=>$rows)));

 ?>
```